# Upper bound Gaussian complexity by Rademacher complexity

Tags: high-dimensional

In [Martin Wainwright's book](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewainwrig/BibPapers/Wai19.pdf) Exercise 5.5 (b), we need to upper bound the Gaussian complexity $\mathcal{G}(\mathbb{T})$ of a set $\mathbb{T}\in\mathbb{R}^d$ by Rademacher complexity $\mathcal{R}(\mathbb{T})$, i.e., to show $\mathcal{G}(\mathbb{T})\leqslant 2\sqrt{\log d}\mathcal{R}(\mathbb{T})$.

In the hint, it suggests to use the Rademacher contraction inequality. Namely, that $\mathcal{R}(\phi(\mathbb{T}))\leqslant \mathcal{R}(\mathbb{T})$ for any contraction $\phi$. What I came up with was that for Gaussian random vector $g\sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_d)$, $\|g\|_{\infty}\leqslant C\sqrt{\log d}$ with high probability. But I'm not sure how to use this to get the desired inequality.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to just give a couple of hints:

- Let $g = (g_i)$ and note that $g_i = |g_i| \text{sign}(g_i)$ with the signs being independent of the magnitudes. So, you can condition on signs without changing the distribution of the magnitudes. Alternatively, you can replace the signs with independent Rademacher variables $\{s_i\}$.
- Conditioned on $\{s_i\}$, in an expression like
  $\sup_{(t_i) \in \mathbb T } \sum_i |g_i| s_i t_i$, you can enlarge $\mathbb T$ in some way to make sure that the supremum occurs at a point where every element of the sum is nonnegative.
- If $a \ge b$, then $c a \ge c b$ for any $c \ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! By following your hints, I can get $\mathcal{G}(\mathbb{T}) \leqslant 2\sqrt{\log d}\mathcal{R}(\tilde{\mathbb{T}})$, where $\tilde{\mathbb{T}}$ is the enlarged set. But I do not get how to connect $\mathcal{R}(\mathbb{T})$ with $\mathcal{R}(\tilde{\mathbb{T}})$.

Comment: Instead, I think I get another way to show the inequality by following the contraction hint. Actually, we have $\mathcal{G}(\mathbb{T}) = \mathbb{E}\sup_{t\in\mathbb{T}}\sum g_i t_i = \mathbb{E}_{\varepsilon,g}\sup_{t\in\mathbb{T}}\sum \varepsilon_i |g_i| t_i = \mathbb{E}_g[\mathbb{E}_{\varepsilon}[\sup_{t\in\mathbb{T}} \sum\varepsilon_i |g_i|t_i \mid g]] \leqslant \mathbb{E}_{g}\|g\|_{\infty}\mathbb{E}_{\varepsilon}\sup_{t\in\mathbb{T}}\sum\varepsilon_i t_i\leqslant 2\sqrt{\log d}\mathcal{R}(\mathbb{T})$. Where the first inequality uses the Rademacher contraction inequality.

Comment: You solution works nicely.